# How can i get window.location.pathname on my test file using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app

I have react app was made by create-react-app using jest and enzyme for testing

So how can i get the value of `window.location.pathname` inside my test file?

This is my spec

```
import React from 'react';
import MovieDetailsBox from '../../src/components/movie_single/MovieDetailsBox';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { movie_details } from '../../src/data/movies_details'
import { empty_user } from '../../src/helper/sessionHelper';

jest.mock('react-router');

describe('Test <MovieDetailsBox /> Component', () => {

    let movie_details_props = {
        movie: {...movie_details}
    }

    let user_props = {

    }

    const context = { router: { isActive: (a, b) => true } }

    const wrapper = shallow(
        <MovieDetailsBox movie={movie_details_props}
                         user={user_props}
                         currentPath={'/movie/68'}/>, { context }
    )

    const movie_data_check = movie_details_props.movie;

    it('MovieDetailsBox call correct function on rating box', () => {
        wrapper.find('.hidden-xs .rate-movie-action-box button').simulate('click')

        if(!empty_user(user_props)){
            expect(window.location.pathname).to.equal('/login')
        } else {
            console.log('have user wow')
        }
    })
})
```

But i got this as an error on my console

```
AssertionError: expected 'blank' to equal '/login'
```

It seems like `window.location.pathname` return blank instead of current url path name.

So how can i fix this or am i need to setup anything else inside setupTests.js file?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share code for MovieDetailsBox?

Comment: It is just a normal react component from `class MovieDetailsBox extends Component`

Answer (score 15):

### **Finally found the solution !**

so you can set the base URL in your Jest config section in your `package.json`

```
"jest": {
 ....
    "testURL": "http://test.com/login"
 ....
 }
```

And for the unit test you can change the window.location.pathname via:

```
window.history.pushState({}, 'Page Title', '/any/url/you/like?with=params&enjoy=true');
```

Answer (score 8):

Add testURL into your configuration file.
For example( package.json ):

```
"jest": {
 ....
    "testURL": "http://test.com/login"
 ....
 }
```

By default jest set window.location.href as "about:blank". After setting testURL, jest use it as test environment url and location.href receive that value.

You can read about it:
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testurl-string

Comment: I've tried nearly every other approach I could find, and I could think of, and it was so simple... RTFM for me, I guess.

Comment: It's not ideal to set this globally.

Answer (score 4):

Try using: `expect(location.pathname).to.equal('/login')`.

In my tests the `location` is a global variable, you can get as if it was `window.location`, and if you need the full path, try: `location.href`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I get the logic of your component, but I suggested to use methods of react-router, instead of window.location.
To push user to specific page use:

```
browserHistory.push('/login');
```

As a result the test can be written significantly easier, use spy() from Sinon.js or spy from Jest https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/mock-functions.html

Example with spy:

```
it('should redirect user to pathname=/delegation if pathname=/play', () => {
    const spyBrowserHistory = spy();
    mobileDelegationRewireAPI.__Rewire__('browserHistory', {
        push: spyBrowserHistory
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(<MobileDelegation {...location} />);
    wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
    expect(spyBrowserHistory.calledOnce).to.be.true;
    expect(spyBrowserHistory.calledWith(`/delegation${location.search}`)).to.be.true;
});
```

So, the idea is test whether or not methods which has to change location is called with correct params.