# Retrieve location.href from jest with jsdom

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsdom

I am trying to use jsdom in Jest to retrieve the pathname. So far I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43568570/how-can-i-get-window-location-pathname-on-my-test-file-using-jest/43568680#43568680), where the testURL is set in the `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "testURL": "http://localhost:3000/"
  }
```

As much as I know, I don't need a jsdom setup file.
So I am using it like that in the test:

```
import { jsdom, location } from 'jsdom';

  it('directs to /question', () => {
  const handleClick = jest.fn();
    const button = shallow(
      <Button handleClick={handleClick} />
    );
    button.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(location.href).toBe("/question")
  });
```

When I do it like that, I always get the error `Cannot read property 'href' of undefined`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to import `location` from jsdom. Jest has it's own `location` object.