# How to mock window.location.href with Jest + Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine, vue-test-utils

Currently, I am implementing unit tests for my project and there is a file that contains `window.location.href`.

I want to mock this to test and here is my sample code:

```
it("method A should work correctly", () => {
      const url = "http://dummy.com";
      Object.defineProperty(window.location, "href", {
        value: url,
        writable: true
      });
      const data = {
        id: "123",
        name: null
      };
      window.location.href = url;
      wrapper.vm.methodA(data);
      expect(window.location.href).toEqual(url);
    });
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: href
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
```

How should I resolve it?

Comment: This has been answered in another thread [Here is the link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56651910/4342108)

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for but `window.location.assign(url)` functionally does the same thing so you could mock that instead using `jest.spyOn(window.location, 'assign').mockImplementation(() => {});`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mock the JavaScript 'window' object using Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885841/how-can-i-mock-the-javascript-window-object-using-jest)

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You can try:

```
window = Object.create(window);
const url = "http://dummy.com";
Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
  value: {
    href: url
  },
  writable: true // possibility to override
});
expect(window.location.href).toEqual(url);
```

Have a look at the Jest Issue for that problem:
[Jest Issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5124)

Comment: For me using `global` didn't work, I removed `global.` and I also needed to add `writable: true` otherwise once set the other tests can't change it.

Comment: typerror: location is not rewritable

Answer (score 123):

### 2020 Update

---

**Basic**

The [URL object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) has a lot of the same functionality as the [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location). In other words, it includes properties such as `pathname`, `search`, `hostname`, etc. So for most cases, you can do the following:

```
delete window.location
window.location = new URL('https://www.example.com')
```

**Advanced**

You can also mock [Location methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#Methods) that you might need, which don't exist on the URL interface:

```
const location = new URL('https://www.example.com')
location.assign = jest.fn()
location.replace = jest.fn()
location.reload = jest.fn()

delete window.location
window.location = location
```

Comment: with typescript update, `delete window.location` will trigger an error `The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional`

Comment: @dhsun any solution to the problem you have mentioned above? I am facing similar issue

Comment: Add // @ts-ignore above the line delete window.location; if you must

Comment: `Reflect.deleteProperty(global.window, 'location')` deals with that without ts error

Comment: To get around that TS error you can do `delete (window as any).location;`

Comment: There is another, seldomly used, property on the Location API: [`ancestorOrigins`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/ancestorOrigins). You might want to mock that, too.

Comment: Why the `window.location` should be deleted? Can't it override it by `window.location = location` only?

Comment: where are you import jest.fn from?

Comment: doesn't work on jasmine

Comment: TypeError: Cannot delete property 'location' of #<Window>

Comment: For TypeScript you can do `window.location = location as unknown as Location`

Answer (score 50):

I have resolved this issue by adding `writable: true` and move it to `beforeEach`

Here is my sample code:

```
global.window = Object.create(window);
const url = "http://dummy.com";
Object.defineProperty(window, "location", {
    value: {
       href: url
    },
    writable: true
});
```

Comment: This solution also works for overwriting `window.location.hostname` in Jest tests. I needed `writable: true` in order to change the `hostname` more than once.

Comment: this helps me a lot

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Best solution for me.

Answer (score 26):

Solution for 2019 [from GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/890):

> ```
> delete global.window.location;
> global.window = Object.create(window);
> global.window.location = {
>   port: '123',
>   protocol: 'http:',
>   hostname: 'localhost',
> };
> ```

Comment: This is the only one that seems to work for me and with a helpful reason why! :)

Comment: It works, but breaks following tests using postMessage that needs the original `location.host` property

Answer (score 24):

The best is probably to create a new [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) instance, so that it parses your string like `location.href` does, and so it updates all the properties of `location` like `.hash`, `.search`, `.protocol` etc.

```
it("method A should work correctly", () => {
  const url = "http://dummy.com/";
  Object.defineProperty(window, "location", {
    value: new URL(url)
  } );

  window.location.href = url;
  expect(window.location.href).toEqual(url);

  window.location.href += "#bar"
  expect(window.location.hash).toEqual("#bar");
});
```

https://repl.it/repls/VoluminousHauntingFunctions

Answer (score 16):

Working example with `@testing-library/react` in 2020 for window.location.assign:

```
  afterEach(cleanup)
  beforeEach(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      writable: true,
      value: { assign: jest.fn() }
    })
  })
```

Comment: `writable: true` was necessary for my unit tests to work otherwise the subsequent tests wouldn't be able to overwrite it to something else. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Many of the examples provided doesn't mock the properties of the original Location object.

What I do is just replace Location object (window.location) by URL, because URL contains the same properties as Location object like "href", "search", "hash", "host".

Setters and Getters also work exactly like the Location object.

Example:

```
const realLocation = window.location;

describe('My test', () => {

    afterEach(() => {
        window.location = realLocation;
    });

    test('My test func', () => {

        // @ts-ignore
        delete window.location;

        // @ts-ignore
        window.location = new URL('http://google.com');

        console.log(window.location.href);

        // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: I wonder if it shouldn't be `const realLocation = Object.assign({}, window.location);` since I feel just assigning it directly would be passing a reference which is later overwritten. Thoughts?

Comment: The object that the original window.location points to is not mutated in this code -- the window.location property has different objects set inside it. Since there's no mutation of the original window object, there's no need to clone it.

Comment: `@ts-ignore` should not be abused if you want to use TS, it is generally a bad practice.

Answer (score 6):

I use the following way using the Jest's mocking mechanism ([`jest.spyOn()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/next/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype)) instead of directly overwriting the object property.

```js
describe("...", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const originalLocation = window.location;
    jest.spyOn(window, "location", "get").mockImplementation(() => ({
      ...originalLocation,
      href: "http://dummy.com", // Mock window.location.href here.
    }))
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks()
  });

  it("...", () => {
    // ...
  })
});
```

I learned it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61760496/13103190).

Answer (score 6):

TS in 2022

```
const orgLocation: Location = window.location;

beforeEach(() => {
  delete (window as any).location;
  window.location = (new URL("http://localhost") as any);
  window.location.assign = ({configurable:true, value:jest.fn()} as any);
  window.location.replace = ({configurable:true, value:jest.fn()} as any);
  window.location.reload = ({configurable:true, value:jest.fn()} as any);
});

afterAll(() => window.location = orgLocation);
```

Answer (score 4):

Extending @jabacchetta's solution to avoid this setting bleeding into other tests:

```js
describe("Example", () => {
  let location;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const url = "https://example.com";
    location = window.location;
    const mockLocation = new URL(url);
    mockLocation.replace = jest.fn();
    delete window.location;
    window.location = mockLocation;
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    window.location = location;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you can try [jest-location-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-location-mock).

```
npm install --save-dev jest-location-mock
```

update `jest` configs at `jest.config.js` file or `jest` prop inside `package.json`:

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: [ "./config/jest-setup.js" ]
```

create `jest-setup.js`

```
import "jest-location-mock";
```

usage:

```
it("should call assign with a relative url", () => {
    window.location.assign("/relative-url");
    expect(window.location).not.toBeAt("/");
    expect(window.location).toBeAt("/relative-url");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

How to reassign window.location in your code base; the simplest working setup we found for our Jest tests:

```js
const realLocation = window.location;

beforeEach(() => {
  delete window.location;
});

afterEach(() => {
  window.location = realLocation;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try a helper:

```
const setURL = url => global.jsdom.reconfigure({url});

describe('Test current location', () => {
  test('with GET parameter', () => {
    setURL('https://test.com?foo=bar');
    // ...your test here
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is valid for Jest + TypeScript + Next.js (in case you use `useRoute().push`

```js
const oldWindowLocation = window.location;

beforeAll(() => {
  delete window.location;
  window.location = { ...oldWindowLocation, assign: jest.fn() };
});

afterAll(() => {
  window.location = oldWindowLocation;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**JSDOM Version**

Another method, using JSDOM, which will provide `window.location.href` and all of the other properties of `window.location`, (e.g. `window.location.search` to get query string parameters).

```js
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

...

const { window } = new JSDOM('', {
    url: 'https://localhost/?testParam=true'
});
delete global.window;
global.window = Object.create(window);
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not find how to test that `window.location.href` has been set with correct value AND test that `window.location.replace()` has been called with right params, but I tried this and it seems perfect.

```js
    const mockWindowLocationReplace = jest.fn()
    const mockWindowLocationHref = jest.fn()
    
    const mockWindowLocation = {}
    Object.defineProperties(mockWindowLocation, {
      replace: {
        value: mockWindowLocationReplace,
        writable: false
      },
      href : {
        set: mockWindowLocationHref
      }
    })
    jest.spyOn(window, "location", "get").mockReturnValue(mockWindowLocation as Location)

    describe("my test suite", () => {
        // ...
        expect(mockWindowLocationReplace).toHaveBeenCalledWith('foo')
        expect(mockWindowLocationHref).toHaveBeenCalledWith('bar')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on examples above and in other threads, here is a concrete example using `jest` that might help someone:

```js
describe('Location tests', () => {
    const originalLocation = window.location;

    const mockWindowLocation = (newLocation) => {
        delete window.location;
        window.location = newLocation;
    };

    const setLocation = (path) =>
        mockWindowLocation(
            new URL(`https://example.com${path}`)
        );

    afterEach(() => {
        // Restore window.location to not destroy other tests
        mockWindowLocation(originalLocation);
    });

    it('should mock window.location successfully', () => {
        setLocation('/private-path');

        expect(window.location.href).toEqual(
            `https://example.com/private-path`
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Is deleting `window.location` necessary?

Comment: Honestly, I don’t remember why a delete ended up being needed there. I guess you can try without it, and if it works then happy times!

Answer (score 0):

Probably irrelevant. But for those seeking a solution for window.open('url', attribute) I applied this, with help of some comments above:

```
window = Object.create(window);
const url = 'https://www.9gag.com';
Object.defineProperty(window, 'open', { value: url });

expect(window.open).toEqual(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one you can use in a `beforeEach` or ala carte per test.

It utilizes the Javascript `window.history` and its `pushState` method to manipulate the URL.

```js
window.history.pushState({}, 'Enter Page Title Here', '/test-page.html?query=value');
```

Comment: can this approach cause side effects in other tests? Your code looks simple and straightforward. But I'm hesitant to apply it, and I prefer to mock `window.location` before tests and restore the original `window.location` after the tests. Like for example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64433986/1429387). Just because I'm sure that it will not affect my other tests in an unpredictable way.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and clean way to do it:

```
 Object.defineProperty(window, "location", {
    value: new URL("http://example.com"),
    configurable: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this issue by re-implementing window.location & window.history: https://gist.github.com/tkrotoff/52f4a29e919445d6e97f9a9e44ada449

It's heavily inspired by https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/5124#issuecomment-792768806 (thx sanek306) and [firefox-devtools window-navigation.js](https://github.com/firefox-devtools/profiler/blob/f894531be77dee00bb641f49a657b072183ec1fa/src/test/fixtures/mocks/window-navigation.js) (thx gregtatum & julienw)

It comes with unit tests and it works well with our source base.

You can then use window.location in your tests like you would expect:

```
it('should ...', () => {
  window.location.pathname = '/product/308072';

  render(<MyComponent />);

  const link = screen.getByRole<HTMLAnchorElement>('link', { name: 'Show more' });
  expect(link.href).toBe('http://localhost:3000/product/308072/more');
});

it('should ...', () => {
  const assignSpy = vi.spyOn(window.location, 'assign');

  render(<MyComponent />);

  const input = screen.getByRole<HTMLInputElement>('searchbox');
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'My Search Query' } });
  fireEvent.submit(input);

  expect(assignSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(assignSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, '/search?query=My+Search+Query');

  assignSpy.mockRestore();
});
```

Here the implementation (copy-pasted from the gist, more details in the gist):

```
/* eslint-disable unicorn/no-null */

/*
 * Resetting window.location between tests is unfortunately a hard topic with JSDOM.
 *
 * https://gist.github.com/tkrotoff/52f4a29e919445d6e97f9a9e44ada449
 *
 * FIXME JSDOM leaves the history in place after every test, so the history will be dirty.
 * Also its implementations for window.location and window.history are lacking.
 * - https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/22.1.0/lib/jsdom/living/window/Location-impl.js
 * - https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/22.1.0/lib/jsdom/living/window/History-impl.js
 * - https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/22.1.0/lib/jsdom/living/window/SessionHistory.js
 *
 * What about Happy DOM? Implementations are empty:
 * - https://github.com/capricorn86/happy-dom/blob/v12.10.3/packages/happy-dom/src/location/Location.ts
 * - https://github.com/capricorn86/happy-dom/blob/v12.10.3/packages/happy-dom/src/history/History.ts
 *
 *
 * window.location and window.history should work together:
 * window.history should update the location, and changing the location should push a new state in the history
 *
 * Solution: re-implement window.location and window.history
 * The code is synchronous instead of asynchronous, yet it fires "popstate" events
 *
 * Inspired by:
 * - https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/5124#issuecomment-792768806
 * - https://github.com/firefox-devtools/profiler/blob/f894531be77dee00bb641f49a657b072183ec1fa/src/test/fixtures/mocks/window-navigation.js
 *
 *
 * Related issues:
 * - https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/5124
 * - https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/890
 * - https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/5987
 * - https://stackoverflow.com/q/54021037
 *
 * - Huge hope on jsdom.reconfigure() (tried by patching Vitest JSDOM env), doesn't work
 *   https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/discussions/2383
 *   https://github.com/simon360/jest-environment-jsdom-global/blob/v4.0.0/environment.js
 *   https://github.com/simon360/jest-environment-jsdom-global/blob/v4.0.0/README.md#using-jsdom-in-your-test-suite
 */

class WindowLocationMock implements Location {
  private url: URL;

  internalSetURLFromHistory(newURL: string | URL) {
    this.url = new URL(newURL, this.url);
  }

  constructor(url: string) {
    this.url = new URL(url);
  }

  toString() {
    return this.url.toString();
  }

  readonly ancestorOrigins = [] as unknown as DOMStringList;

  get href() {
    return this.url.toString();
  }
  set href(newUrl) {
    this.assign(newUrl);
  }

  get origin() {
    return this.url.origin;
  }

  get protocol() {
    return this.url.protocol;
  }
  set protocol(v) {
    const newUrl = new URL(this.url);
    newUrl.protocol = v;
    this.assign(newUrl);
  }

  get host() {
    return this.url.host;
  }
  set host(v) {
    const newUrl = new URL(this.url);
    newUrl.host = v;
    this.assign(newUrl);
  }

  get hostname() {
    return this.url.hostname;
  }
  set hostname(v) {
    const newUrl = new URL(this.url);
    newUrl.hostname = v;
    this.assign(newUrl);
  }

  get port() {
    return this.url.port;
  }
  set port(v) {
    const newUrl = new URL(this.url);
    newUrl.port = v;
    this.assign(newUrl);
  }

  get pathname() {
    return this.url.pathname;
  }
  set pathname(v) {
    const newUrl = new URL(this.url);
    newUrl.pathname = v;
    this.assign(newUrl);
  }

  get search() {
    return this.url.search;
  }
  set search(v) {
    const newUrl = new URL(this.url);
    newUrl.search = v;
    this.assign(newUrl);
  }

  get hash() {
    return this.url.hash;
  }
  set hash(v) {
    const newUrl = new URL(this.url);
    newUrl.hash = v;
    this.assign(newUrl);
  }

  assign(newUrl: string | URL) {
    window.history.pushState(null, 'origin:location', newUrl);
    this.reload();
  }

  replace(newUrl: string | URL) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, 'origin:location', newUrl);
    this.reload();
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line class-methods-use-this
  reload() {
    // Do nothing
  }
}

const originalLocation = window.location;

export function mockWindowLocation(url: string) {
  //window.location = new WindowLocationMock(url);
  //document.location = window.location;
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    writable: true,
    value: new WindowLocationMock(url)
  });
}

export function restoreWindowLocation() {
  //window.location = originalLocation;
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    writable: true,
    value: originalLocation
  });
}

function verifyOrigin(newURL: string | URL, method: 'pushState' | 'replaceState') {
  const currentOrigin = new URL(window.location.href).origin;
  if (new URL(newURL, currentOrigin).origin !== currentOrigin) {
    // Same error message as Chrome 118
    throw new DOMException(
      `Failed to execute '${method}' on 'History': A history state object with URL '${newURL.toString()}' cannot be created in a document with origin '${currentOrigin}' and URL '${
        window.location.href
      }'.`
    );
  }
}

export class WindowHistoryMock implements History {
  private index = 0;
  // Should be private but making it public makes it really easy to verify everything is OK in some tests
  public sessionHistory: [{ state: any; url: string }] = [
    { state: null, url: window.location.href }
  ];

  get length() {
    return this.sessionHistory.length;
  }

  scrollRestoration = 'auto' as const;

  get state() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return
    return this.sessionHistory[this.index].state;
  }

  back() {
    this.go(-1);
  }

  forward() {
    this.go(+1);
  }

  go(delta = 0) {
    if (delta === 0) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
    const newIndex = this.index + delta;
    if (newIndex < 0 || newIndex >= this.length) {
      // Do nothing
    } else if (newIndex === this.index) {
      // Do nothing
    } else {
      this.index = newIndex;

      (window.location as WindowLocationMock).internalSetURLFromHistory(
        this.sessionHistory[this.index].url
      );

      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
      dispatchEvent(new PopStateEvent('popstate', { state: this.state }));
    }
  }

  pushState(data: any, unused: string, url?: string | URL | null) {
    if (url) {
      if (unused !== 'origin:location') verifyOrigin(url, 'pushState');
      (window.location as WindowLocationMock).internalSetURLFromHistory(url);
    }
    this.sessionHistory.push({
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
      state: structuredClone(data),
      url: window.location.href
    });
    this.index++;
  }

  replaceState(data: any, unused: string, url?: string | URL | null) {
    if (url) {
      if (unused !== 'origin:location') verifyOrigin(url, 'replaceState');
      (window.location as WindowLocationMock).internalSetURLFromHistory(url);
    }
    this.sessionHistory[this.index] = {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
      state: structuredClone(data),
      url: window.location.href
    };
  }
}

const originalHistory = window.history;

export function mockWindowHistory() {
  //window.history = new WindowHistoryMock();
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'history', {
    writable: true,
    value: new WindowHistoryMock()
  });
}

export function restoreWindowHistory() {
  //window.history = originalHistory;
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'history', {
    writable: true,
    value: originalHistory
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can rewrite window.location by delete this global in every test.

```
delete global.window.location;
const href = 'http://localhost:3000';
global.window.location = { href };
```

Comment: Why deleting? Why just reassignment doesn't work?