# Why is Window.location.search undefined even when Window.location.href includes a query string?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom

I've written a function to get the value of a given query string based on David Walsh's [Get Query String Parameters](https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript).

```js
export const getQueryStringValue = (name) => {
  const formattedName = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
  const regex = new RegExp(`[\\?&]${formattedName}=([^&#]*)`);
  const results = regex.exec(window.location.search);

  return results === null
    ? ''
    : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
};
```

I've written a test for the function based on [How to mock window.location.href with Jest + Vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54021633/11809808).

```js
it('should return query string value', () => {
  global.window = Object.create(window);
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: {
      href: 'http://dummy.com?foo=bar'
    }
  });

  expect(getQueryStringValue('foo')).toBe('bar');
});
```

However, when I run the test I get the following error.

```sh
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "bar"
Received: ""
```

And when I console log `window.location.search` it returns `undefined`.

```
  console.log __tests__/getQueryStringValue.test.js:14
    undefined
```

Why does Window.location search return `undefined` even when Window.location.href includes a query string (`?foo=bar`)? Shouldn't setting href be enough?

Comment: It could be because in the define property the value is an object with only href, so the search attribute is undefined

Comment: @HaibraynGonzález That makes sense. It makes me wonder: how does the browser set `window.location.search` when a page loads?

Comment: Why does it fail? Your mock is wrong. You are only setting href, it is not going to automatically set up the other methods of location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window.location search doesn't get automatically mocked when you set Window.location href because [jsdom does not currently handle navigation](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#reconfiguring-the-jsdom-with-reconfiguresettings). You have a couple options to resolve the error.

#### Option 1: Set Window.location Search

```js
it('should return query string value', () => {
  global.window = Object.create(window);
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: {
      search: '?foo=bar'
    }
  });

  expect(getQueryStringValue('foo')).toBe('bar');
});
```

#### Option 2: Set Window.location To New [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) Instance

```js
it('should return query string value', () => {
  global.window = Object.create(window);
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: new URL('http://dummy.com/?foo=bar')
  });

  expect(getQueryStringValue('foo')).toBe('bar');
});
```

*Source:* https://stackoverflow.com/a/59979453/11809808

Comment: "I don't know why ", because it was not mocked.... You do not get all of the properties for free.

Comment: @epascarello "because it was not mocked.... You do not get all of the properties for free". That answers my question. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I posted an answer there that should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59979453/3702797

Comment: @Kaiido I've updated my answer based on your link. Thanks for providing that answer. I actually prefer it to my original answer.