# How to mock window.location.href with Jest in React?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-hooks, mocking

I'm testing functionality that is not supposed to run locally and need to mock `window.location.href`:

```js
const usePageTracking = (): void => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!window.location.href.includes("localhost")) {
      ReactGA.initialize("UA-000000-01");
      ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
    }
  }, []);
};
```

In my tests:

```js
describe("usePageTracking", () => {
  it("initializes ReactGA", () => {
    render(<Example />);
    expect(ReactGA.initialize).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it("tracks page view", () => {
    render(<Example />);
    expect(ReactGA.pageview).toHaveBeenCalledWith("/");
  });
});
```

Note: there's a [related question around Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021037/how-to-mock-window-location-href-with-jest-vuejs/63382670) but it wasn't clear to me if the solutions apply to React as well (some just didn't work).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ended up with the following on React 16 and Jest 24.

```js
describe("usePageTracking", () => {
  let location;
  const mockLocation = new URL("https://example.com");

  beforeEach(() => {
    location = window.location;
    mockLocation.replace = jest.fn();
    // You might need to mock other functions as well
    // location.assign = jest.fn();
    // location.reload = jest.fn();
    delete window.location;
    window.location = mockLocation;
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    window.location = location;
  });

  // ...
});
```

See also:

- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/890
- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5124

Answer (score 10):

Use `Object.defineProperty()` to define a getter for `window.location`.

E.g.

`usePageTracking.ts`:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const usePageTracking = (): void => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(window.location.href);
  }, []);
};
```

`Example.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { usePageTracking } from './usePageTracking';

export function Example() {
  usePageTracking();
  return <div>example</div>;
}
```

`Example.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Example } from './Example';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

describe('Example', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
      get() {
        return { href: 'stackoverflow.com' };
      },
    });
    render(<Example />);
  });
});
```

test result

```
 PASS  examples/63409476/Example.test.tsx (11.048 s)
  Example
    ✓ should pass (39 ms)

  console.log
    stackoverflow.com

      at examples/63409476/usePageTracking.ts:5:13

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.768 s
```

package versions:

```json
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
}
```

Comment: Object.defineProperty() worked perfectly with typescript!