# React Testing Library clears hash after click on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

In our single-page application, switching between pages is realized with `window.location.hash`. And I found a problem in React Testing Library unit-tests - triggering click on `<a/>` tag clears `window.location.hash`. For example, when I am on the "Info" page, my hash is equal to `'#info'`. And when I click on `<a />` element, hash does not change. But in the tests hash becomes an empty string `''` after doing same thing.

Here's a short *test that doesn't work*:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

test('Test', async () => {
    window.location.hash = 'hash';
    render(<a className="some-class">Some text</a>);
    await userEvent.click(screen.getByText('Some text'));
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 30));
    expect(window.location.hash).toEqual('#hash');
});
```

And here's it *error message*:

```
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: "#hash"
Received: ""
```

The problem is with anchor tag. Test with the `span` tag works OK:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

test('Test', async () => {
    window.location.hash = 'hash';
    render(<span className="some-class">Some text</span>); // <span /> instead of <a />
    await userEvent.click(screen.getByText('Some text'));
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 30));
    expect(window.location.hash).toEqual('#hash');
});
```

**Question** How can I avoid this behavior? I can't just get rid of `a` tags in the code, because most of the basic components is declared in another npm library.

**EDIT 1** I don't really want to check `location.hash`. I want to check page's content, which is depends on `location.hash` value. And the real problem is: when `location.hash` becomes empty string some of the content disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63409477/4774045), this behavior its more like a `jsdom` issue. And to accomplish the expected value you should do something like this:

```js
const oldLocation = window.location;

describe("matching cities to foods", () => {

  afterEach(() => {
    // AFTER EACH TEST, set it to the original object.
    window.location = oldLocation;
  });

  test("Test", async () => {
    // delete only for this test
    delete window.location;

    // Change only the hash option and keep the rest same as the original.
    window.location = { ...oldLocation, hash: "hash" };

    render(<a className="some-class">Some text</a>);

    await userEvent.click(screen.getByText("Some text"));

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 30));

    expect(window.location.hash).toEqual("hash");
  });
});
```

Comment: That's instresting. But what if I need to change hash in the source code? I don't think that deleting `window.location` on the client side is a good idea

Comment: Also, in your example you're checking that hash is equal to `hash` but in production it would be `#hash`

Comment: An option related to delete window, is do something like the other SO - set the original value after each test - (i've updated the answer).

Comment: And related to hash, as you are mocking it, the expected value should be without the `#`, unless you set with it before.