# Cypress: Can I stub/mock the window.location.hostname in a test?

Tags: testing, mocking, cypress

I have a component that should not appear on a list of hostnames, and want a cypress test to test the logic around that.

I know with my Jest unit tests, I can use `delete global.window.location.hostname` then `global.window.location.hostname = "whatever"` but can't seem to find a Cypress equivalent.
(Ref [How to mock window.location.href with Jest + Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021037/how-to-mock-window-location-href-with-jest-vuejs/57612297#57612297))

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I notice in your question you have the code `delete global.location.hostname` but in the SO answer you referenced, it's `delete global.window.location`. Which did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress has the [cy.location()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location#Syntax) command, but there appears to be a getter but no setter.

You could try

```
cy.window().then(win => win.location.hostname = 'newvalue');
```

or

```
cy.state('window').location.hostname = 'newvalue';
```

No need to delete it first.

Comment: Sadly, have tried both. With the cy.window() option, my websocket for the localhost disconnects and fails - and cy.state() triggers a page load in the test runner which it waits for and never happens so timesout and fails.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like Cypress views it as a redirect, see [Native Location](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/location#Native-Location) says **When changing properties on the real window.location object, it forces the browser to navigate away.**. So I'm wondering why do you not get this navigation behavior with Jest? Could you post the complete Jest test for context.