# Testing redirect routes with Redux-Saga/Fetch-mock in React

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux-saga

I'm trying to test when a redirect of a route happens in redux-saga. All other tests are passing except this one, which I have not figured out how to test.

This is the saga function that I'm testing...

```
export function* doFetch({ payload: { id } }) {
  try {
    const station = yield call(stationApi.fetch, id)
    yield put(set(station))
    const allStations = yield call(stationApi.fetch)
    const cashDrawer = yield call(buildCashDrawerState, station, allStations)
    yield put(replaceCashDrawerState(cashDrawer))
    yield call(redirectPos, station)
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(notifyError(
      'Something went wrong during the station fetch. Please try again later',
      { id: 'station' },
    ))
  }
}
```

This is the redirect method...

```
const redirectPos = (station) => {
  if (window.location.href.includes('pos') && station.cash_drawer) {
    sagamore.router.redirect('pos')
  } else if (!station.cash_drawer) {
    sagamore.router.redirect('sales/dashboard')
  } else {
    return
  }
}
```

And this is the test so far...

```
fdescribe('sagas/station', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    fetchMock.restore()
  })

  fdescribe('doFetch', () => {
    it('fetches station and cash drawer', () => {
      const id = 1
      const station = {
        id,
        name: 'new name',
        cash_drawer: { location_id: 'location', id: 2 },
      }
      const stations = [
        { id: 10, name: 'Station1', cash_drawer_id: 2 },
        { id: 11, name: 'Station2', cash_drawer_id: 2 },
        // { id: 12, name: 'Station3', cash_drawer_id: 3 },
      ]
      fetchMock.mock(
        `/api/stations/${id}`,
        station,
      )
      fetchMock.mock(
        `/api/stations`,
        { results : stations },
      )
      const saga = doFetch({ payload: { id } })
      let expected
      expected = call(stationApi.fetch, id)
      expect(saga.next().value).toEqual(expected)
      expected = put(set(station))
      expect(saga.next(station).value).toEqual(expected)
      expected = call(stationApi.fetch)
      expect(saga.next().value).toEqual(expected)
      saga.next({ results: stations })
      expected = put(replaceCashDrawerState({ drawer: {...station.cash_drawer, stations: stations} }))
      expect(saga.next({ drawer: {...station.cash_drawer, stations: stations} }).value).toEqual(expected)
      // test redirectPos(...)
      expected = call(redirectPos, station)
      expect(saga.next().value).toEqual(expected)
    })
  })
})
```

I'm new to Redux-Saga and testing. I haven't been able to find a way to test this when researching it. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when you write unit test the idea is to test every unit in isolation. So in your case, from the saga perspective the logic inside of `redirectPos` doesn't matter, all you need to test is that it gets called with the right parameter. Then, you can write another test specifically for the `redirectPos` function where you test the internals.

Testing current location can get a bit tricky, I suggest visiting other SO questions on that topic such as [How to mock window.location.href with Jest + Vuejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021037/how-to-mock-window-location-href-with-jest-vuejs)